# Allow pushing exact same commit

Tags: git

Is there a way to force git to push a commit to a remote branch even when that remote branch already points to the same commit?

An example use case for this is to trigger post-push actions, such as on Heroku.

Comment: TL;DR: No, but you can push an empty commit.

Comment: That's the workaround I'm using now. Came here looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: The linked duplicate lists a few. But that's about the best you can get.